# How can I create an Inline assembly command with a multi-variable register offset?

Tags: gcc, arm, inline-assembly

The following code, using gcc for ARMv4, is perfectly fine:

```
asm("strb.w r2, [r0, #24 + 8 * 1]");
```

Now, if I try the following:

```
asm("strb.w r2, [r0, %[offset] + %[delta] * %[scale]]"
    :: [offset] "i" (24), [delta] "i" (8), [scale] "i" (1)
);
```

I get

```
strb.w r2, [r0, #24 + #8 * #1]
```

which clearly is wrong. How can I accomplish this?

```
asm("strb.w r2, [r0, #24 + 8 * 1]");
```

Comment: How about `"strb.w r2, [r0, %[offset] + %c[delta] * %c[scale]]"`?  `%c` is discussed [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Generic-Operand-Modifiers).

Comment: @DavidWohlferd That did the trick! many thanks for taking the time to even show where this is documented. Much appreciated.

Comment: Since they are fixed constants (and the assembler will not work if they aren't), you can get the compiler to do the math instead of the assembler.  Well, the Q/A is correct, the purpose is dubious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning the comment into an answer since it seems to work:

Looking at the [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Generic-Operand-Modifiers) for inline asm, we see there is a modifier that can be used for "i".  Adding `c` will:

> Require a constant operand and print the constant expression with no punctuation.

So changing your code to something like this should give you what you want:

```
asm("strb.w r2, [r0, %[offset] + %c[delta] * %c[scale]]"
    :: [offset] "i" (24), [delta] "i" (8), [scale] "i" (1)
);
```

BTW: While this may give you what you're after, as a general rule I recommend that you [don't use inline asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm) (despite how powerful and cool it is).  Obviously I don't know your specific requirements, but there are good reasons to avoid inline asm when possible.